Updating Log4J2 Appender's file path at Runtime
For a project, I have a programm that is started multiple times, and I want to log every run of it into a different File. I already have everything in place I need for this, e.g. a variable holding the intended logging location for a specific run.
The problem now is that I cannot manage to update the RollingFileAppenders of the LoggerContext correctly. It seems that they are being created correctly, and then I also seem to be able to replace the old Appender by the new one correctly, but when I actually execute some log.debug(...) or whatever, the Configuration always returns to the old Appenders for some reason. The logging then goes nowhere, not even into the file the Appender was previously set to.
I have already looked into the documentation, but this seems to suggest that what I am doing should be working.
Right now, this is what I am doing:
LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();
RollingFileAppender oldAppender = config.getAppender(appenderName);

if (oldAppender != null) {
    oldAppender.stop();

    if (!newBasePath.endsWith("\\")) {
        newBasePath += "\\";
    }
    if (!logFileName.endsWith(".log")) {
        logFileName += ".log";
    }
    String newFileName = newBasePath + logFileName;
    String newFilePattern = newBasePath + "model_%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log.gz";

    // Create a new RollingFileAppender with the new file path, reusing the old configuration
    RollingFileManager manager = oldAppender.getManager();
    RollingFileAppender newAppender = RollingFileAppender.newBuilder()
                .setName(appenderName)
                .withFileName(newFileName)
                .withFilePattern(newFilePattern)
                .withAppend(manager.isAppend())
                .withStrategy(manager.getRolloverStrategy())
                .withPolicy(manager.getTriggeringPolicy())
                .setLayout(oldAppender.getLayout())
                .withLocking(manager.isLocking())
                .build();
    newAppender.start();
//...

This produces a new Appender with the exact same settings as the old one, except for the write location, which is what I intended. I confirmed this in the debugger.
//remove old appender from Config and Loggers
...
    ((PropertiesConfiguration) config).removeAppender(appenderName);
    config.getLoggers().values().forEach(l -> l.removeAppender(appenderName));
    //add rebuilt (new) appender to Config and Loggers
    config.addAppender(newAppender);
    config.getLoggers().values().forEach(l -> l.addAppender(newAppender, l.getLevel(), l.getFilter()));

    context.updateLoggers();
}

This removes the old Appender from the current LoggerContext's Configuration and inserts the new one. In the Debugger, I can see that this also seems to work as intended.
This screenshot shows the Logger before changing to the new Appender (notice old log file path in the variables):
Before setting new Appender
This is after executing the next few lines (notice the new log file paths):
After setting new Appender
Immediately after this, I test the Appender via some log.debug(...), but when I debug into the code, I see that the Appenders are back to the old file path:
Calling log.debug(...) immediately after updating Appender
I suspect that it somehow resorts to some default configuration that is inferred from the log4j2.properties and not affected by the changes I made.
The debug level should not be the problem, since all levels in the log4j2.properties are set to DEBUG.

I just want to ask about the rules. Do you give a similar job id (for example, 800) every time the program is executed, and then save the log to the path of /logs/800/app.log, and leave the other contents unchanged?

Yes, every run of the program, the program is initialized with a different job ID. Other variables may also be initialized differently, but this does not matter for this problem.

In your code I don' see you: 1. Adding the new appender to a LoggerConfig (appenders are resolved by name only at configuration time, not at runtime). 2. Removing the old appender (should happen before the close() call, but after the new appender is functional).

I believe this is done in the second code snippet, or does this not suffice?

log4j2.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Appenders>
    <Routing name="RoutingAppender1">
      <Routes pattern="${ctx:jobId}">
        <Route>
          <RollingFile name="JobLog" fileName="logs/job-${ctx:jobId}.log"
                       filePattern="logs/job-${ctx:jobId}-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
              <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
              <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
              <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
            </Policies>
          </RollingFile>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Routing>
    <Routing name="RoutingAppender2">
      <Routes pattern="${ctx:jobId}">
        <Route>
          <RollingFile name="JobLog" fileName="logs/${ctx:jobId}/app.log"
                       filePattern="logs/${ctx:jobId}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
              <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
              <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
              <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB"/>
            </Policies>
          </RollingFile>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Routing>    
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="RoutingAppender1"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="RoutingAppender2"/>      
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>

DemoApp.java
package com.example;


import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;

public class DemoApp {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(DemoApp.class);
    public static void executeJob(String jobId) {
        //Set jobId as a variable of ThreadContext
        ThreadContext.put("jobId", jobId);
        logger.info("Job " + jobId + " is starting...");
        // job execution logic
        ThreadContext.clearAll();  // Clear context variables to prevent contamination
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadContext.put("jobId", "ZZZ");
        
        //Test English
        String msg = "Hello World!";
        System.out.println( msg );
        logger.info(msg);
        logger.warn(msg);
        logger.error(msg);

        executeJob("280");

        //Test CJK
        ThreadContext.put("jobId", "ZZZ-ZH");
        String msgCJK = "你好 世界 !";
        System.out.println( msgCJK );
        logger.info(msgCJK);
        logger.warn(msgCJK);
        logger.error(msgCJK);

    } //main

} //class

Output logs:
RoutingAppender1
logs
├── job-280.log
├── job-ZZZ.log
└── job-ZZZ-ZH.log

RoutingAppender2
logs
├── 280
│   └── app.log
├── ZZZ
│   └── app.log
└── ZZZ-ZH
    └── app.log


Your answers as usual give the right solution, but don't explain anything. Could you explain briefly in the answer why Routing Appender is the right tool for the job? There is also an inherent security risk in creating files based on the thread context: some applications might populate it from the headers of an HTTP request.

Your question is very good: what will happen "if" it is used in a web program, (some applications might populate it from the headers of an HTTP request). The problem is that the questioner did not give more usage scenarios. So I can only give a proof of concept. Program example. Even, I don’t know whether this answer can meet the needs of the questioner. I can only give you proof-of-concept code. Then test it to make sure it meets the questioner's needs. As for satisfying various situations, I think there is Difficult. I can only test for a certain situation.

In addition, because I am not a native English speaker, I use Google Translate for a lot of my content.

This answer has an Issue. After calling executeJob, ThreadContext.clearAll(); will be executed. If the jobId is not set in the subsequent program (ThreadContext.put("jobId", "ZZZ-ZH"); ), will cause log4j to output the log to the wrong file name and directory. You will get job-${ctx:jobId}.log and ${ctx:jobId} directories. When ThreadContext is empty and there is no jobId, an error will occur.

The example has a couple of bugs: 1. The one your mention: it doesn't handle the case when jobId is not set. You can handle that case with a <Route key="$${ctx:jobId}"> route (see the "Using appender references" example), 2. It doesn't escape the lookup in <Routes> to pattern="$${ctx:jobId}". Unlike the lookups in the children of Route, this one is evaluated eagerly at configuration time.

Awesome, this solved it! Thank you!
